# googletest install on Ubuntu 16.04 - make errors

Tags: c++, unit-testing, ubuntu, googletest

I'm trying learn/install the Google Test Framework.  I basically tried to follow these instructions to install it on Ubuntu 16.04:

1. sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev
2. cd /usr/src/gtest
3. sudo cmake CMakeLists.txt
4. sudo make

On `sudo make` it outputs a lot of errors (screenshot below).  Initially it was complaining about c++11. So, I added `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` to the CMakeLists.txt file which actually seem to help but now I'm having the errors below.

Has anyone encountered this or have any idea on how to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Recently, I was building it for macOS. It worked fine: http://www.owsiak.org/setting-up-googletest-on-macos/ - If you are looking for Linux based install, take a look here: https://gitlab.com/mkowsiak/converter-docker where I use googletest inside Docker. Take a look at `Dockerfile`.

Comment: what compiler and version are you using? did you try downloading and compiling the newest gtest version?

Comment: i'm using `gcc version 5.4.0` and I think the latest gtest version. I'm not sure how to check that, but I just downloaded it today.  I restarted again and followed along with @Oo.oO DockerFile.  From a quick look I think this way might be working for me now.